# Creating onmouseover function for separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onmouseover

Alright I'll try to make this as clear as possible. Be kind, I'm very new to JavaScript.

I have a div container called nav, that holds five navigation buttons and they're all floated side by side. Under that container I have a div container called underbar, which is just a solid color bar under each nav element. When someone hovers on a navigation div, the color of the underbar for that element changes. Right now, I have what you see below, and it is working correctly.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="nav">
<div id="one" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ubone').style.background='gray'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ubone').style.background='white';"><a href="one.html">One</a>    </div><!-- end of first nav -->
<div id="two" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ubtwo').style.background='gray'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ubtwo').style.background='white';"><a href="two.html">Two</div><!-- end of second nav -->
<div id="three" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ubthree').style.background='gray'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ubthree').style.background='white';"><a href="three.html">Three</div><!-- end of third nav -->
<div id="four" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ubfour').style.background='gray'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ubfour').style.background='white';"><a href="four.html">Four</div><!-- end of fourth nav -->
<div id="five" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ubfive').style.background='gray'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ubfive').style.background='white';"><a href="five.html">Five</div><!-- end of fifth nav -->
</div><!-- end of nav div -->

<div id="underbar">
<div id="ubone"></div><!-- end of first nav -->
<div id="ubtwo"></div><!-- end of second nav -->
<div id="ubthree"></div><!-- end of third nav -->
<div id="ubfour"></div><!-- end of fourth nav -->
<div id="ubfive"></div><!-- end of fifth nav -->
</div><!-- end of underbar div -->

</div><!-- end of container div-->
```

This works fine, yes. However, I absolutely hate the thought of having to go in and edit these one by one, by one. What's the easiest way to simplify this using a javascript function / jquery (preferably) while being able to do it for multiple div ids? Thoughts / opinions? Thanks!

Comment: With jQuery, you can do away with all the inline JavaScript.

Comment: You also have invalid HTML... the closing `</a>` tag is missing on most of your links.

Comment: Please don't edit your question with your answer and a whole new question... it renders all your previous answers as obsolete and leads to tremendous confusion.

Comment: Chokey I think I can avoid doing that in the future. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This targets the `div`'s that are a direct child of your `#nav` element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav > div').mouseover(function(){

        $('#ub' + this.id).css('backgroundColor', 'grey');

    }).mouseout(function(){

        $('#ub' + this.id).css('backgroundColor', 'white');

    });
});
```

If you want a pure Javascript solution then try this:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#nav > div');

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    {
        elements[i].onmouseover = function(){
            document.querySelector('#ub' + this.id).style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
        };
        elements[i].onmouseout = function(){
            document.querySelector('#ub' + this.id).style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: jQuery `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` would work better.  Or `.hover()` which combines them.

Comment: How do I go about applying this code to the divs? I linked the jquery hosted by google. I also created a mouse-events.js javascript page with the code above and linked it to my html page. I'm just not sure what else needs to be done? TYVM! Very clean reply, and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You don't _apply_ to the `div`'s... this code already _targets_ the `div`'s.

Comment: @user1504591 I edited the answer with a pure javascript solution as well. Have a look how I have used document.ready and window.onload. Using those, the code will execute when the page loads. For the jQuery, include the library and throw my code anywhere on the page. For the pure Javascript, just throw the code anywhere on the page (within <script> tags of course).

Comment: Gotcha... in that case. Not working? lol Or atleast for me. Again, I linked the jquery, linked the js page I made from the above code, and I remove the onmouseover / mouseout settings from the html page, stripping it to just the div id and the text inside that div. Wonder what I'm doing wrong.. herm. Will keep checking into this. Perhaps I need to alter a CSS element? Thanks

Comment: Try to get it working with the code on the same page (to rule out the include). Post your full code to the question and I'll take a look. Also keep an eye on the error console for messsages to indicate what's wrong.

Comment: @user1504591 you need to add the document.ready(function(.. wrapper that I added to my code. Your code won't work because the elements don't exist at the time that it executes. If you add the document.ready wrapper, it executes on load instead.

Comment: @user1504591, if you can't get this working, glance at the jsFiddle demo in my answer to see it in action.

Comment: @MrCode Working perfectly now, TYVM! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".myClass").mouseover(function() {
    $('#ub' + this.id).css('background-color', 'gray');
  }).mouseout(function(){
     $('#ub' + this.id).css('background-color', 'white');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an answer [with a working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AVk6k/1/):**

http://jsfiddle.net/AVk6k/1/

And using [jQuery `.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead.  `.hover()` is like a shorthand that combines `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` into one handler.

IMHO, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are much more reliable than `mouseover` and `mouseout`, which tend to flicker.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav div').hover(
    function() {
        $('#ub' + this.id).css('background-color', 'grey');
    }, function() {
        $('#ub' + this.id).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});​
```

You also had some missing `</a>` tags.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="one"><a href="one.html">One</a></div><!-- end of first nav -->
        <div id="two"><a href="two.html">Two</a></div><!-- end of second nav -->
        <div id="three"><a href="three.html">Three</a></div><!-- end of third nav -->
        <div id="four"><a href="four.html">Four</a></div><!-- end of fourth nav -->
        <div id="five"><a href="five.html">Five</a></div><!-- end of fifth nav -->
    </div><!-- end of nav div -->
    <div id="underbar"> 
        <div id="ubone"></div><!-- end of first nav -->
        <div id="ubtwo"></div><!-- end of second nav -->
        <div id="ubthree"></div><!-- end of third nav -->
        <div id="ubfour"></div><!-- end of fourth nav -->
        <div id="ubfive"></div><!-- end of fifth nav -->   
    </div><!-- end of underbar div -->   
</div><!-- end of container div-->​
```

Comment: Although I have a working example now using MrCodes script. I'm interested in trying yours because of the .hover vs the mouseover and mouseout. I'm pretty much pulling my hair out because for some reason something that should be so easy to recreate from your JS fiddle is not yielding the same results. My process? Link to jquery with google in the head i.e <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> then copy the html and save as "test.html". create Test.css and link your css from the test.html page. Create a page and save as test.js, and copy / paste js.

Comment: @user1504591, I'm not understanding where you could be going wrong.  The HTML is exactly yours except I added the missing `</a>` tags and removed the inline JS.  Ignore my CSS; I added that because yours was missing.  You can see the jsFiddle is working... so just look at the JavaScript section and apply the minor changes to your code.  Then use your browser's developer console to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Working now. I'm unable to tell you why or what I did, as I just came back to it today. Why couldn't I have just been a welder... THX!

Answer (score 1):

All solutions provided uses jQuery to achieve what you want. Using plain Javascript (which is much faster), use this approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hoverMenu(elem)
{
    document.getElementById('ub' + elem.id).style.background='gray';
}

function blurMenu(elem)
{
    document.getElementById('ub' + elem.id).style.background='white';
}
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="one" onmouseover="hoverMenu(this);" onmouseout="blurMenu(this);"><a href="one.html">One</a>    </div><!-- end of first nav -->
        <div id="two" onmouseover="hoverMenu(this);" onmouseout="blurMenu(this);"><a href="two.html">Two</div><!-- end of second nav -->
        <div id="three" onmouseover="hoverMenu(this);" onmouseout="blurMenu(this);"><a href="three.html">Three</div><!-- end of third nav -->
        <div id="four" onmouseover="hoverMenu(this);" onmouseout="blurMenu(this);"><a href="four.html">Four</div><!-- end of fourth nav -->
        <div id="five" onmouseover="hoverMenu(this);" onmouseout="blurMenu(this);"><a href="five.html">Five</div><!-- end of fifth nav -->
    </div><!-- end of nav div -->

    <div id="underbar">
        <div id="ubone"></div><!-- end of first nav -->
        <div id="ubtwo"></div><!-- end of second nav -->
        <div id="ubthree"></div><!-- end of third nav -->
        <div id="ubfour"></div><!-- end of fourth nav -->
        <div id="ubfive"></div><!-- end of fifth nav -->
    </div><!-- end of underbar div -->
</div><!-- end of container div-->
```

Comment: Working perfectly. My only question is document.getElementById('ub' <-- So I don't have to use the entire name of the id?

Comment: Quote Matheus: _"plain Javascript (which is much faster)"_ ~  If you're going to make a statement like that, please quantify.  How much faster and will it make any practical difference for the user experience?

Comment: This isn't much cleaner than the original. Pure JS doesn't mean you have to be obtrusive with your event handlers.

Comment: @user1504591 No. The functions will automate that for you.

Comment: @Sparky672 I just can't see a point of including a library in the project just to do a simple task, since he was already using Vanilla JS. And of course plain Javascript will be faster. Not only in the processing, but also in bandwidth. Want numbers? http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: You can't see the point, yet the OP specifically stated that he preferred a jQuery solution.... for learning, or maybe his project is more complex, etc?  And I don't dispute that it's faster... I dispute that the difference will be noticeable in an average practical application.

Comment: I didn't saw that part that he wanted a jQuery solution (an edit maybe)... Anyway. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nav").on("mouseover", "div", function() {
    $('#ub' + this.id).css('backgroundColor', 'gray');
}).on("mouseout", "div", function() {
    $('#ub' + this.id).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
});
```

Comment: Why are we using `getElementById()` within a jQuery solution?

Comment: Because it is closest to the initial code and that vanilla JS remains faster than jQuery :)

Comment: So don't use jQuery at all.

Comment: OK, ok :) Just for the fun (as they were many other working solutions), I have updated my answer. Personaly, I prefer use `on` with a selector rather than other solutions mentioned above that's why I let it there...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Misread the question.  Here is my amended answer.**

I would suggest a more semantically correct markup.  As your navigation is effectively a list of links, it is generally standard practice to style it as such:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li rel="#ubone"><a href="mypage1.html">One</a><li>
  <li rel="#ubtwo"><a href="mypage2.html">Two</a><li>
  <li rel="#ubthree"><a href="mypage3.html">Three</a><li>
  <li rel="#ubfour"><a href="mypage4.html">Four</a><li>
</ul>
```

This does require a little extra styling to remove the default list styles, but results in a navigation that makes more sense to Google web crawlers, and follows good coding practices.  If in doubt, here is a start on the css:

```
#nav {margin:0; padding:0;}
#nav li {list-style:none; float:left; padding:5px 10px; background:#FFF;}
#nav a {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
```

To answer your original question you can add the behaviour using jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // The document ready waits for the document to load before adding JS to the elements
  // We use the css selector for our element to select it, then use the hover function to apply a behaviour
  $('#nav li').hover(function(){
    // This function executes when the mouse hovers over the li
    var target = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(target).css({
      'background' : '#ccc'
    });
  }, function(){
    // This function executes when the mouse leaves the li
    var target = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(target).css({
      'background' : '#fff'
    });        
  });
});
```

If you need more help with jQuery, head over to http://api.jquery.com/ where they have some excellent in depth documentation.

**N.B.** - Without seeing the actual styles you're applying I can't be sure, but it sounds like your underbar could also be accomplished by adding a bottom border and then changing the colour on hover using the ":hover" css pseudo-class.

Comment: Pure CSS can't modify another element, only the hovering element.

Comment: Use the delete/undelete link when your answer is hidden.

Comment: My apologies, like I said I misread the question.  Thanks for the tip Sparky672, I'm still getting the hang of Stackoverflow so will remember that for next time.